# mod_rewrite ignoring rule when a folder exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched and searched, can't find this issue anywhere.

The setup we have isn't ideal, this is related to an API.

### /.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api$ /system/api.php [L,NC]
```

### /api/2/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/2/
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

### Folder structure

```
/
    /.htaccess
    /api
        /2
            /index.php <--- My API 2 file
            /.htaccess
    /system
        /api.php
```

### The problem

I need users to be able to access the legacy API at /api or /api/ until our new API is ready.

I need users to be able to access the new API at /api/2/ too.

.htaccess, mod_rewrite is ignoring the $ (end of string) on the /api$ rule. There are no rules in there to ignore it for directories, so why is it doing this?

#### What Should Happen- At least what I want to happen

Requests to /api?URLParam=Hello - Should result in requests being routed to /system/api.php

Requests to /api/2?URLParam=Hello - Should result in requests going to /api/2/index.php

#### What actually happens

Requests to /api?URLParam=Hello - These are returned a 301 Redirect to Requests to /api/ (Note the trailing slash) - This wouldn't usually be an issue, but we have a lot of jQuery POST calls to /api (without a trailing slash). When they are redirected, the POST data is lost, resulting in a failed API call to /api/

Requests to /api/2?URLParam=Hello - Works fine.

### What I have tried

- Basic htaccess file as you can see.
- Ignore /api and /api/
- Ordering of rules
- -f -d flags with both ! and no inverter.

#### Temporary fix

When I remove the /api/ directory, the calls to /api?Param=Hello work without any issues at all, with no 301 redirects. But obviously this stops /api/2/ calls.

I can't figure it out - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off trailing slash by using `DirectorySlash Off` and add an optional trailing slash in your `root .htaccess`:

**/.htaccess file**

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/?$ /system/api.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much, genius.